# What are nonstandard forms of written words called?

Tags: terminology

Normal characters are (汉)字 and *nonstandard* characters are 俗子.

Wrongly written words or nonstandard forms of written words can be referred to by using *俗作*.

For instance, the entry for *耳食* in《南充方言词语考释》says:

> “耳食”俗作“耳屎”、“耳视”等。

What are these types of words called?

异形词 is an, obvious, option. I would like to be more specific noting that it is a 俗 problem.

俗词 would just talk about current terms or expressions, vulgarities or familiar language.

What is the proper term for nonstandard forms of written words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**异形词** is the broad term.

A more specific, albeit obscure and probably not widely accepted term would be: **俗体词**.

Usage of 俗体词 can be found on this Zhihu question: [英译中里俗体词和异音词如何处理？](https://www.zhihu.com/question/24394835)

> 俗体词（比如错音错意、用词不当等）

Although it is talking about English, it should be clear enough to be understood in Chinese as well.

Answer (score -2):

aren't they called 異體字 (variant character)?

http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/home.do

if this one doesn't suit your need, maybe:

"後起字", "分化字", "古今字",  or "訛變"

Comment: Not characters but words. Perhaps words are just 异形词 and nothing more. Maybe 俗形词 could work?

Comment: might we invent 異體詞 to describe variant words :)

Comment: The term 异形词 is already accepted though! (and I believe I've asked that before on Chinese SE). https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/23184/4136 俗体词 on the other hand does look like another valid option.